# Dumb error in my if/and statement - not seeing it

Tags: python, if-statement, subset

I have a data set with float values:

```
dog-auto        dog-bird        dog-cat         dog-dog         Result
41.9579761457   41.7538647304   36.4196077068   33.4773590373   0
46.0021331807   41.33958925     38.8353268874   32.8458495684   0
42.9462290692   38.6157590853   36.9763410854   35.0397073189   0
41.6866060048   37.0892269954   34.575072914    33.9010327697   0
39.2269664935   38.272288694    34.778824791    37.4849250909   0
40.5845117698   39.1462089236   35.1171578292   34.945165344    0
45.1067352961   40.523040106    40.6095830913   39.0957278345   0
41.3221140974   38.1947918393   39.9036867306   37.7696131032   0
41.8244654995   40.1567131661   38.0674700168   35.1089144603   0
45.4976929401   45.5597962603   42.7258732951   43.2422832585   0
```

This is an SFrame. I have attempted to write a function that uses an if/an statement to determine if the value for dog-dog is less that the values for dog-ct AND dog-auto AND dog-bird.

I've gone through this for the better part of 4 hours. Admittedly I'm a newby to python - I'm making a illy mistake and just not seeing it.

If statement:

```
def is_dog_correct(row):
    if (dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-dog']] < dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-cat']]) & (dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-dog']] < dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-bird']]) & (dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-dog']] < dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-auto']]):
        dog_distances['Result'] = 1
    else:
        dog_distances['Result'] = 0
```

then I call the function with:

```
dog_distances.apply(is_dog_correct)
```

If this was working correctly, I would see "0" in every row but the fifth record. What is wrong with my if statement?

Full disclosure - this is coursework, but after spending 4 hours on this, I'm reaching for help!

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operation. Change all your `&` to `and`

Comment: What is `dog-distances` that it has both string and (apparently) floating-point keys? And why are you using `&` instead of `and`?

Comment: Your function takes a `row` argument but never uses it...

Comment: I assume you are actually passing in the row you want as a dictionary, and have your loop elsewhere? You'll need more context for anyone to help you appropriately

Comment: I did switch to "AND" instead of &. Still not working.

Comment: I am calling the loop with dog_distances.apply(is_dog_correct)

Answer (score 1):

Change & to and as indicated by the previous comments. Also, I recommend you break up such long if statements into multiple lines so it's clearer and easier to read.

```
def is_dog_correct(row):
    if (dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-dog']] < dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-cat']]) and 
       (dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-dog']] < dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-bird']]) and
       (dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-dog']] < dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-auto']]):
        dog_distances['Result'] = 1
    else:
        dog_distances['Result'] = 0
```

Comment: Ok @Informat, I changed it to the exact code shown above, but still doesn't seem to be getting through the conditions. Now I'm wondering if this is doing a boolean operation in the background (True/False) - am I making an error by trying to set value to Result = 1 or Result = 0? Thanks for your thoughts! I appreciate your help!

Comment: Can i see how you've defined and set up dog_distances?

Answer (score 0):

Make your first if statement more clean by finding the `min` (minimum) of all of the values. This makes sure that 'dog-dog' is less than all of the rest:

```
def is_dog_correct(row):
    if dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-dog']] < min([dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-'+x]] for x in ['cat','bird','auto']]):
        dog_distances['Result'] = 0
    else:
        dog_distances['Result'] = 1
```

**EDIT**: For debuggin purposes use the following:

```
def is_dog_correct(row):
    print 'dog is {}'.format(dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-dog']])
    print 'everyone else is {}'.format([dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-'+x]] for x in ['cat','bird','auto']])
    if dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-dog']] < min([dog_distances[dog_distances['dog-'+x]] for x in ['cat','bird','auto']]):
        print 'Yay dog is faster'
        dog_distances['Result'] = 0
    else:
        print 'Awww, dog is not faster'
        dog_distances['Result'] = 1
```

Comment: That's interesting, but I need to determine if the dog-dog value is less than each of the values. Perhaps your code will determine which value is the minimum of all three and then run the condition? If that's true, then maybe would work - I'll try it and let you know. Thank's for your consideration!

Comment: I popped it in, but result was seeing all values set to 1 (rather than 0), but the one row in the HEAD portion shown above which should have been 0 is still showing 1. So...the if conditions still not recognizing that the dog-dog value is less than the dog-bird value in row 6 (shown above) Thank's for your consideration!

Comment: You're welcome. They should be all ones except for the last row, because 43.2 is not less than 42.7.

Comment: I missed that row, but row six and the last row should be 0, given dog-dog isn't less than one of the other three column values. How would I test whether or not the conditions are being read at all? If it isn't catching that item, I'm concerned I'm seeing "1" values for the wrong reason. Any idea why it wouldn't display the "0" values correctly?

Comment: I can send you the Jupiter notebook and datasets if that would be helpful

Comment: @LucasH.Scanlon Are your values strings or integers? (as well as the dog-values?)

Comment: all data columns are floats (dog-dog, dog-cat, etc), the Result column is integer

Comment: @LucasH.Scanlon I fixed my post. I believe you want the result to be 1 for those which are false (i.e. the else clause)